# python eliminate almost duplicates CSV

Tags: python, csv

i have a large csv file with this type of data

```
192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
192.168.177.85,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
192.168.177.85,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
```

I have been able to eliminate true duplicates but i need to take out the "other" that are also labeled "infection" not sure how to go about it ?
below is my code to remove duplicate's and duplicate connections and the ones with messages other than the three i need  I just cant figure how to now remove the ones that have other and also infection or cnc as a duplicate 
basically from the example above remove the two connections with the "other" in them when i remove the duplicate "other" i need to keep track if it was a "infection" or "cnc" also just a basic count of each

```
    with open(r'alerts.csv','r') as in_file, open('alertsfix.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set() # set for fast O(1) amortized lookup
    for line in in_file:
        if line in seen: continue # skip duplicate

        seen.add(line)
        out_file.write(line)
in_file.close()
out_file.close()


'''
   writes new file eliminates cross connections sorce and dest 
 '''
s1='"other"'
s2='"infection"'
s3='"cnc"'

with open('alertsfix.csv','r') as in_file, open('alertsfixmore.csv','w') as out_file:
    seen = set()
    for line in in_file:
        lines = line.strip()
        if len(lines) > 0:
            src_ip, src_port, dst_ip, dst_port, msg = lines.split(',')
            src = '{}:{}'.format(src_ip, src_port)
            dst = '{}:{}'.format(dst_ip, dst_port)
            key = frozenset([
                frozenset([src, dst]),
                msg,
            ])

            if key not in seen:
                seen.add(key) # we add 'key' to the set
                s4 = msg
                if s4 in (s1,s2,s3): # eliminate any other types                    
                  out_file.write(line)  # we write 'line ot' to the new file
in_file.close()
out_file.close()
```

Comment: Looks like a problem for `pandas`. Could be solved with groupby everything but the event, then counting the type of event for each group. Could you provide the label for each column in your csv?

Comment: Can there be a `cnc` and `infection` and `other` for the same IP address?

Comment: src,srcport,dest,destport,msg  those are the rows       the same adress with different message is what i need to filter out with infection and CNC being higher priority than other so those are the ones i need to remove other and leave the cnc or infection>the file has some others that are benign so i cant just filter other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the rows on index 0; then group by index 0; for each group filter out all `"other"`'s; inspect what is left over and count `"infection"`'s and `"cnc"`'s; add the rows left over to a new container.

```
import io, csv, itertools

f = io.StringIO('''192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
192.168.177.85,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
192.168.177.85,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
192.168.177.111,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"cnc"
192.168.177.111,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
192.168.177.222,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
192.168.177.222,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"cnc"
192.168.177.222,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"''')

reader = csv.reader(f)
data = list(reader)
data.sort(key=lambda item: item[0])
groups = itertools.groupby(data, lambda item: item[0])
newdata = []
infection, cnc = 0, 0
for key, group in groups:
    group = [row for row in group if row[-1] != "other"]
    infection += sum(row[-1] == "infection" for row in group)
    cnc += sum(row[-1] == "cnc" for row in group)
    newdata.extend(group)
```

---

```
In [18]: cnc
Out[18]: 2

In [19]: infection
Out[19]: 3

In [20]: newdata
Out[20]: 
[['192.168.107.87', '4662', '69.192.30.179', '80', 'infection'],
 ['192.168.177.111', '4662', '69.192.30.179', '80', 'cnc'],
 ['192.168.177.222', '4662', '69.192.30.179', '80', 'infection'],
 ['192.168.177.222', '4662', '69.192.30.179', '80', 'cnc'],
 ['192.168.177.85', '4662', '69.192.30.179', '80', 'infection']]
```

---

Depending on what you are actually trying to do, you may need to sort and group by more than one column - the example data looks like it would also work with a key of `lambda item: item[:-1]`.

Comment: thank you that was a big help in the right direction it helped me solve the issue

Comment: If your solution is different than my answer, feel free to [answer your own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could also keep the information of all the events that happened, and their counts:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

In []: f = StringIO('''192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
    ...: 192.168.107.87,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
    ...: 192.168.177.85,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
    ...: 192.168.177.85,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
    ...: 192.168.177.111,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"cnc"
    ...: 192.168.177.111,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"
    ...: 192.168.177.222,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"infection"
    ...: 192.168.177.222,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"cnc"
    ...: 192.168.177.222,4662,69.192.30.179,80,"other"''')

In []: df = pd.read_csv(f, names=['IP_1', 'port_1', 'IP_2', 'port_2', 'event'])

In []: df
Out[]:
              IP_1  port_1           IP_2  port_2      event
0   192.168.107.87    4662  69.192.30.179      80      other
1   192.168.107.87    4662  69.192.30.179      80  infection
2   192.168.177.85    4662  69.192.30.179      80  infection
3   192.168.177.85    4662  69.192.30.179      80      other
4  192.168.177.111    4662  69.192.30.179      80        cnc
5  192.168.177.111    4662  69.192.30.179      80      other
6  192.168.177.222    4662  69.192.30.179      80  infection
7  192.168.177.222    4662  69.192.30.179      80        cnc
8  192.168.177.222    4662  69.192.30.179      80      other

In []: pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['event']).groupby(list(df.columns[:-1]), as_index=False).sum()
Out[]:
              IP_1  port_1           IP_2  port_2  event_cnc  event_infection  event_other
0   192.168.107.87    4662  69.192.30.179      80          0                1            1
1  192.168.177.111    4662  69.192.30.179      80          1                0            1
2  192.168.177.222    4662  69.192.30.179      80          1                1            1
3   192.168.177.85    4662  69.192.30.179      80          0                1            1
```